# How can we detect if a water melon contains artificial colouring?

Tags: food, fruits-and-vegetables

Recently I heard at the market that water melons are injected with artificial colouring to make them look fresh and attractive, even though it is very harmful for anyone who consumes them.

Is there a way to check a water melon for artificial colouring before buying?

Comment: I couldn't find a confirming source, however, as far as I know biologically certified melones are not allowed to contain chemical additives.

Comment: @orschiro I guess you mean [certified organic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organic_certification). Some languages (German, Italian, French, Czech, etc.) use their equivalent of the English "biological" to refer to "certified organic".

Comment: "*Recently I heard*" I think you should back that up with an actual claim **describing what substance they are colored with**. Without that information, how can anyone tell you how to detect 'it'? Also, your addition *it is very harmful* makes very little sense without that info. Anyone can say anything.

Comment: I agree with Jan Doggen. This question needs more information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Put a dime sized piece of watermelon pulp in a glass. Add 1 tablespoon of white vinegar and stir. Wait 30 seconds. If the vinegar stays clear then there is no artificial coloring. If it changes to any other color, then coloring has been added!

Comment: I guess this only works after buying the water melon, although, if what you say works, it is one way to check whether a particular vendor sells artificially coloured melons. Why vinegar?

Comment: We can't always take some vineger to market and check for it. But is there a way to check practically ?

Comment: Let a tissue soak some vinegar, rub the melon with it.

Answer (score 0):

Stick with certified organic as already suggested the price difference from convental to orginic is next to neal.  Visit ["The national List"](http://www.whfoods.com/genpage.php?tname=faq&dbid=47), Evaluation criteria for allowed and prohibited substances, methods, and ingredients.

This same websight has [watermelon](http://www.whfoods.com/genpage.php?tname=foodspice&dbid=31#purchasequalities) as a superfood you will be well informed to visit .

Answer (score 0):

Yes few sources do inject sucrose based colors via injections two to three days prior it is sent to market . 
Such water melons have sugar taste rather then it's own .

Comment: The question asks about *before* buying the melon. To taste it, you would have to buy it, I guess...

Answer (score 0):

The vinegar sounds good, but if you are seen doing that in the store you, I'm sure, automatically bought it.  The only ones you can check are the ones that are cut in sections with see through covers on them.